# What permission is required for an Azure B2C app to create a user in the B2C tenant?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I need to migrate users from a legacy application to Azure B2C.

I'm using this code sample for this: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/user-migration/tree/master/pre-migration

I've created an app in the B2C directory and given following permissions.

[image]

But when the application invokes the user creation endpoint I'm getting this error.

[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via Postman and got below results:***

I registered one application in B2C directory and added same **API permissions** as you like this:

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** using authorization code flow with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id:<appID>
grant_type:authorization_code
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
code:code
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
client_secret: <secret>
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I tried to create B2C user using above access token with below query, I got **similar error** as below:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
Content-type: application/json

{
  "displayName": "Sri Test",
  "identities": [
    {
      "signInType": "userName",
      "issuer": "sritenantb2c.onmicrosoft.com",
      "issuerAssignedId": "sritest"
    },
    {
      "signInType": "emailAddress",
      "issuer": "sritenantb2c.onmicrosoft.com",
      "issuerAssignedId": "xxxsridevim@microsoft.com"
    }
  ],
  "passwordProfile" : {
    "password": "password-value",
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": false
  },
  "passwordPolicies": "DisablePasswordExpiration,DisableStrongPassword"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **resolve** the error, make sure to add below **`Delegated`** API permissions like this:

[image]

After granting consent to above permissions, I generated **access token** again via Postman like below:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id:<appID>
grant_type:authorization_code
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
code:code
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
client_secret: <secret>
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token in below query, I got response successfully:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
Content-type: application/json

{
  "displayName": "Sri Test",
  "identities": [
    {
      "signInType": "userName",
      "issuer": "sritenantb2c.onmicrosoft.com",
      "issuerAssignedId": "sritest"
    },
    {
      "signInType": "emailAddress",
      "issuer": "sritenantb2c.onmicrosoft.com",
      "issuerAssignedId": "xxxsridevim@microsoft.com"
    }
  ],
  "passwordProfile" : {
    "password": "password-value",
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": false
  },
  "passwordPolicies": "DisablePasswordExpiration,DisableStrongPassword"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, **B2C user** created successfully like below:

[image]

In your case, make sure to add **Delegated** permissions like `User.ReadWrite.All` or `Directory.ReadWrite.All` in your application by granting admin consent based on your requirement.

**UPDATE:**

`User.ReadWrite.All` is enough if you want to restrict access as per minimum privileges criteria.

Comment: Are you sure `Directory.ReadWrite.All` is necessary?

Comment: `User.ReadWrite.All` is enough if user want to limit it to minimum privileges.